# Concentration for sum of order statistics

Tags: pr.probability

Assume we draw $n$ numbers uniform i.i.d. from $[0,1]$, and let the least $k$ of them be $x_1,\dots,x_k$. It is well-known that their expectations are $\frac{1}{n+1},\dots,\frac{k}{n+1}$, so the expectation of their sum is $\frac{k(k+1)}{2(n+1)}$. But is there a concentration bound saying that, with high probability as $n\rightarrow\infty$, this sum doesn't exceed $\alpha\cdot\frac{k(k+1)}{2(n+1)}$ for some given parameter $\alpha$?

These $k$ variables are not independent, so we cannot apply Chernoff bound. I found a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.7209.pdf) with a related title, but it is not easy to tell if something in there answers this question.

Comment: Do you view $k$ as fixed?

Comment: It could be fixed, but could also be a function of $n$.

Comment: If $k$ and $\alpha$ are fixed and $n\to\infty$, the statement isn't true in fact. For example, the probability that $x_1$ exceeds $\alpha(k+1)/(2(n+1))$ converges to $e^{-\alpha(k+1)/2}$ -- in that case the sum $x_1+\dots+x_k$ certainly exceeds the given threshold. For $k\to\infty$, a useful approach may be that $x_{k+1}$
concentrates, and then conditional on $x_{k+1}$, the sum $x_1+ \dots+x_k$
has the same distribution as $x_{k+1}(U_1+\dots+U_k)$ where $U_i$ are i.i.d. $U[0,1]$,  to which you can indeed apply Chernoff or whatever.

Comment: Can't you just do this as a calculus problem? The joint density of the order statistics is $n!$ where it is non-zero, so the probability that $x_1+\ldots +x_k\le b$ equals $n!$ times the volume of the region defined by this condition and $0\le x_1\le x_2\le \ldots \le x_n\le 1$.

Comment: More specifically, this gives $P(x_1+\ldots +x_k\le s)= \binom{n}{k}\int\ldots\int (1-t)^{n-k}\, dt_1\ldots dt_k$, where the integration is over $t_1+\ldots +t_k\le s$, and $t=\max t_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\D}{\overset{D}=}$Let $X_{n:1},\dots,X_{n:n}$ denote the order statistics in question. Fix any real $t>0$. You wanted to show that for natural $k\le n$
\begin{equation*}
    p_{n,k}:=P\Big(\sum_{j=1}^k X_{n:j}
    \ge(1+t)\frac{k(k+1)}{2(n+1)}\Big)\to0 \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
as $n\to\infty$. As [noted by James Martin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463406/concentration-for-sum-of-order-statistics#comment1203138_463406), \eqref{10} will fail to hold unless $k\to\infty$.

So, we henceforth assume that $k\to\infty$ (and hence $n\to\infty$), and then we will show that \eqref{10} holds. Moreover, we will obtain an explicit upper bound on $p_{n,k}$, which goes to $0$ exponentially fast with $k$.

First here, consider the gaps
\begin{equation*}
    G_i:=X_{n:i}-X_{n:i-1}
\end{equation*}
between the order statistics for $i=1,\dots,n+1$, where $X_{n:0}:=0$ and $X_{n:n+1}:=1$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    X_{n:j}=\sum_{i=1}^j G_i
\end{equation*}
for $j=1,\dots,n$.

Next, recall that
\begin{equation*}
    (G_1,\dots,G_{n+1})\D\frac{(Y_1,\dots,Y_{n+1})}{Y_1+\dots+Y_{n+1}}, 
\end{equation*}
where $\D$ means the equality in distribution and $Y_1,\dots,Y_{n+1}$ are independent random variables each with the exponential distribution with mean $1$ -- see e.g.
[Exercise 20, page 103](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_First_Course_in_Order_Statistics/gUD-S8USlDwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=standard%20exponential%20random). So,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{j=1}^k X_{n:j}=\sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{i=1}^j G_i
    =\sum_{i=1}^k (k-i+1)G_i\D\sum_{i=1}^k iG_i \\ 
    \D\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}Y_i}. 
\end{equation*}
So, taking some $\ep\in(0,1)$ small enough so that
\begin{equation*}
    \de:=(1+t)(1-\ep)-1>0, \tag{15}\label{15}
\end{equation*}
we see that
\begin{equation*}
    p_{n,k}=P\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}Y_i}
    \ge(1+t)\frac{k(k+1)}{2(n+1)}\Big)\le p_n+q_k, \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    p_n:=P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}Y_i<(1-\ep)(n+1)\Big),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    q_k:=P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^k iY_i\ge(1+\de)\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\Big). 
\end{equation*}
Further, for any real $h>0$, by the Bernstein--Chernoff inequality,
\begin{equation*}
    p_n=P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(1-Y_i)>\ep(n+1)\Big) \\ 
    \le e^{-h\ep(n+1)}E\exp h\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(1-Y_i)
    =\Big(\frac{e^{h(1-\ep)}}{1+h}\Big)^{n+1}.
\end{equation*}
The latter expression is minimized in $h$ when $h=\ep/(1-\ep)$, and then we get
\begin{equation*}
    p_n\le p_{n,\ep}:=\big((1-\ep)e^\ep\big)^{n+1}; \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
note that $p_{n,\ep}\to0$ exponentially fast with $n$, because $(1-\ep)e^\ep<1$.

Further yet, for any real $h\in(0,1/k)$, again by the Bernstein--Chernoff inequality,
\begin{equation*}
    q_k\le\exp\Big\{-h(1+\de)\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\Big\}
    E\exp h\sum_{i=1}^k iY_i \\ 
    =\exp\Big\{-h(1+\de)\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\Big\}\prod_{i=1}^k\frac1{1-hi}. 
\end{equation*}
Note now that $g(u):=\frac1u\,\ln\frac1{1-u}$ is increasing in $u\in(0,1)$, from $g(0+)=1$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \frac1{1-u}=e^{g(u)u}\le e^{g(u_0)u} \tag{35}\label{35}
\end{equation*}
for $u\in(0,u_0]$, and
\begin{equation*}
    g(u_0)<1+\de
\end{equation*}
if $u_0>0$ is small enough. So, letting now $h=u_0/k$ and using \eqref{35} with $u=hi$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    q_k\le q_{k,\ep,u_0}
    :=\exp\Big\{-u_0(1+\de-g(u_0))\frac{k+1}{2}\Big\}, \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
and $q_{k,\ep,u_0}\to0$ exponentially fast with $k$.

Collecting \eqref{20}, \eqref{30}, and \eqref{40}, we get
\begin{equation*}
    p_{n,k}\le p_{n,\ep}+q_{k,\ep,u_0},
\end{equation*}
and the latter upper bound on $p_{n,k}$ converges to $0$ exponentially fast with $k$. The optimal choice of the parameters $\ep,u_0$ (with $\de$ defined in \eqref{15}) depends on the value of $t>0$ in \eqref{10} and on how fast $k$ grows in relation with $n$.